# The same floating action button on different fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, floating-action-button

I'm using a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` to show a list of fragments, every fragment has a floating action button. When I swipe to change between fragments obviously the floating action button change too, so my question is, is it possible to maintain only a floating action button doesn't change when I swipe between fragments?

The activity code

```
package client.tclient.com.client;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FollowingActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TweetFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener{

    ListView homeList;
    SwipeRefreshLayout mySwipeRefreshLayout;
    FloatingActionButton fab;

    MyPagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager mviewPager;
    private List<Fragment> listaFragments;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_following);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);


        listaFragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
        listaFragments.add(TweetFragment.newInstance(1));
        listaFragments.add(TweetFragment.newInstance(2));
        listaFragments.add(TweetFragment.newInstance(3));


        // Creamos nuestro Adapter
        mPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                listaFragments);

        // Instanciamos nuestro ViewPager
        mviewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

        // Establecemos el Adapter
        mviewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }

}
```

the fragment code

```
package client.tclient.com.client;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link TweetFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link TweetFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class TweetFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public static final TweetFragment newInstance(long id){
        TweetFragment tf = new TweetFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle(1);
        bundle.putLong("TWEET_ID",id);
        tf.setArguments(bundle);

        return tf;
    }
    public TweetFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment TweetFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static TweetFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        TweetFragment fragment = new TweetFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View inflate = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tweet, container, false);
        TextView text =(TextView) inflate.findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setText(Long.toString(getArguments().getLong("TWEET_ID")));

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) inflate.findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Se presionó el FAB", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        return inflate;
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p/>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't change"? Since you have a `ViewPager`, are you expecting to have only one button on top of it? So that it doesn't swipe with the content. Please clarify.

Comment: Yes I want only one button which doesn't swipe with the rest of the content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it possible to maintain only a floating action button doesn't change when I swipe between fragments?

This is definitely possible, just create one `FloatingActionButton` in your activity's layout on top of your `ViewPager` via XML. You can achieve that with `CoordinatorLayout`.

There are a lot of examples of using an action button in an activity, I think in your case the only difference is that you use a `ViewPager` instead of an `ImageView` which makes no difference to the FAB implementation. Also, remove the button from fragment's layout because you don't need it to be displayed on each page.

After you implement the layout add an `onClickListener` to that button in your activity. If you need to use some data from the current fragment in a `ViewPager` you can get its index by calling `mviewPager.getCurrentItem()` so this shouldn't be a problem.

If you have more specific question then please narrow it as much as possible so that we can answer in a more precise way.